typename deduction of derived classes
I want to write template method that returns pointer to one of the fields in this class. Those fields are all derived classes of abstract class Space (that is, Edge, Corner and Center) and this can be determined based on the value of the enum class (Position) passed as an argument.
template<typename T>
T* Quadrant::GetSpace(Position p) const;

Is it possible to write it in such a way that I don't have to specify what type of the returned pointer should be each time?

Why not just have GetEdge, GetCorner and GetCenter?

I'm expecting that I'll need to iterate over it in random order in terms of field type, so I wanted to encapsulate this logic in one method

You seem to want the same expression to have different types based on the run-time value of a parameter. That's impossible; the type must be known at compile time. Nor would it have been particularly useful; suppose you managed to implement what you want - how do you envision the calling code would use this facility?

If Position parameter is in fact known at compile time, then a syntax like GetSpace<Position::Corner>() could be made to return a Corner* - but at that point, you could just as well make it GetCorner()

Position is more precise than just corner, it also tell which corner

That doesn't change much; e.g. you could make it Corner* GetCorner(Position which_corner) Again, show how you intend to use GetSpace. Show an example of the calling code.

Types are fixed at compile time so it is a bit unclear how exactly you plan to iterate.
